# Get SQS Queue Name from existing queue ARN in CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS Queue ARN as an input to my CloudFormation template, How do I reference Queue Name or URL from Queue ARN?

In other words, how do I get a CloudFormation Logical Queue from the ARN?(so that I can use GetAtt to reference all the attributes)

Comment: How is the queue being created? Can you export its name from cloudformation when you create it, then reference it in your other template https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html

Comment: @TheClassic Let's say I do not own the queue, I only am given the Queue ARN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't pass in the name from whatever is creating the queue, then you can get the queue name from the arn. Use Fn::Split to split the arn on colons. Then use Fn::Select to select the last string in the list. This will be something like

```
{ "Fn::Select" : [ "5", { "Fn::Split": [":", {"Fn::Sub": "QueueArn"}]}] }
```

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html for a full list of the functions you can use.

Comment: This works now but I have seen multiple recommendations on not to rely on the Queue ARN format

Comment: @Abhishek For other people with the same problem, it'd be good if you could summarise the other recommendations. Also the format of the queue arn is well known and fixed so if you choose to, it is safe to rely on it.